# PyQt: Always on top

Tags: python, pyqt

This is on PyQt4, Linux and Python 2.5

Can I make PyQt set my window "always on top" over other applications?

For example, in GTK i use the property: Modal.

Now, in PyQt I am using a QWidget, but, I can't find a way to do that.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Pass the QMainWindow the `WindowStaysOnTopHint` [window flag](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) (or use setWindowFlags).

As in the name, this is a hint to the windowing manager (not a hard guarantee).

Simplest possible example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class mymainwindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mywindow = mymainwindow()
mywindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)` be simplified by writing: `super().__init__(self, None, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)`?

Comment: Is there a way to make the window pop the the front when its created, but not always stay on top?

Comment: @NuclearPeon It's the same only if you're using single inheritance.

https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/

Answer (score 26):

```
setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

`setwindowaFlags` is a method that can call it from `form` object and just take one parameter is a constant `QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint` that refer to make your form Stays On Top

Comment: maybe you can add a one line explication ?

Answer (score 2):

**For both frameless window(no header) and Always on top.**
USE:
`setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)`

*NOTE: If you try to set as individually window flags, then frameless window won't work.* 
E.g: Below code won't result in frameless and Always on Top window

```
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```