# PyQt4 : How can i toggle the "Stay On Top" behavior?

Tags: python, pyqt4, stayontop

I want to create an app, where the user will decide it the main window will stay always on top of the other apps.

In PyQt4 it is easy to create a window that will stay always on top. This is covered here : [PyQt: Always on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925015/pyqt-always-on-top)

What I want to have a widget (menu item, checkbox etc) that will toggle this behavior on or off. So far i haven't found a way to reset the original behavior.

thank you

UPDATE
After the suggestion of İsmail 'cartman' Dönmez, I searched a bit more and I found an implementation of the WindowFlags example in PyQt4.

It can be found [here](http://blindvic.livejournal.com/9437.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should disable it:

```
window.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

This should enable it:

```
window.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

Comment: It took me a while to find that one should call `windowFlags()` to preserve `Qt.WindowFlags` type. If I try to use XOR and build up flags from scratch (in my case `Qt.Dialog ^ Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint`), I get `TypeError` as I end up with `int` instead of `Qt.WindowFlags`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It shows way to disable/enable this

Answer (score 5):

Rosh is correct. But don't forget to include window.show() after you change the flag.  Your window will be hidden when the flag is changed.  I have also included the code for toggling the flag.

This will clear it:

window.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

This will enable it:

window.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

This will toggle it:

window.setWindowFlags(window.windowFlags() ^ QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

Answer (score 4):

You want the `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` hint, see [Window Flags Example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/widgets-windowflags.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually the PyQt version of the example can be found here : http://blindvic.livejournal.com/9437.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to comment on [Rosh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4850757/5045057), so noting here - for PyQt 5.7 on Devuan, if you toggle the WindowStaysOnTopHint flag on a QDialog after it is shown, the window disappears and you need to show() it again immediately after. Other than this it works.