# Stay window on the top with PySide

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have got an app which is written in Pyside. I would like to use a checkbox to my app window show always on the top.

```
class RemoteWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
"""
This is the main window for the capacitiveRemote which contains the remote
itself for controlling the boxes and shortcuts to starting scripts.
"""
def __init__(self):
    super(RemoteWindow, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()
```

This is my function

```
def stayOnTop(self):
    if self.checkBoxTop:
        self.checkBoxTop.setStyleSheet("color: green")
        self.QMainWindow.setWindowFlags(QMainWindow.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
```

This is the checkbox

```
#Stay on the top Checkboxes 

        self.checkBoxTop = QtGui.QCheckBox('Stay on top', self)
        self.checkBoxTop.setMaximumWidth(90)
        self.checkBoxTop.setChecked(0)
        self.checkBoxTop.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.stayOnTop(),
        )
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check out [PyQt4 : How can i toggle the “Stay On Top” behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4850584/1248974), ignore "PyQt4" keyword as the code also works in PySide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 def stayOntop(self):

    if self.checkBoxTop:
        self.checkBoxTop.setStyleSheet("color: green")
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() ^ QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.show()

    else: 
        self.checkBoxTop.setStyleSheet("color: black")
```

Comment: `self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)` looks easier.