# PyQt4: Stop Window from taking Focus

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

What I am trying to do is make an on screen keyboard.
To do this I need to stop the Program from taking focus away from other windows.
Here is the code I have that keeps the window on top.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, Qt
class mymainwindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, None, QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mywindow.show()
app.exec_()
```

(Note: Example from [Keep Window on Top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925015/pyqt-always-on-top))
So what I want to do is add code to stop the window taking focus.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change focus policy of window and all of its contents `QWidget::setFocusPolicy`

Comment: I have tried using the setFocusPolicy with it set to NoFocus,
Are you able to provide a example please?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that you need to do it for ALL controls. QPush/Tool/OtherButton has default policy different than NoFocus