# pyqt5 (x11) make window stay on bottom

Tags: python, x11, pyqt5

This has been solved in the comments by [ekhumero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro), thank you ;)

---

I  need to have my window stay on bottom.

There is the windowOnTop flag, [as dicussed here (here using pyqt4, but it's an well enough example)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1925015/pyqt-always-on-top), but is there a way to achieve the exact opposite?

I'm using Linux (Manjaro) with X11, so I'll accept X11 specific answers too, if they work with pyqt5, cross plattform compatibillity is no concern.

Comment: So you're saying you tried `Qt.WindowStaysOnBottomHint` and it didn't work?

Comment: Haven't found that one on my googling, I feel a slight bit embarassed right now... but doesn't work. Might be my window manager, though, so I'll test on something more icccm ans netwm compliant to see if this problem is on my end.

Comment: I tested the [pyqt5 widget-flags example](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/widgets/windowflags.py) on arch linux with the openbox window manager and it works fine for me.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, my Internet broke down :(   Tested with openbox too, works like a charm, thank you ;D marking this a solved as fast as I'm not forced to use my cell to get online.